# segmentation fault (core dumped)

Tags: loops, segmentation-fault, pthreads

I feel as though the problem is staring me right in the face. I've narrowed the cause of the issue to essentially one line. 'pthread_create' is where the issue arises. Below is the code I have.

```
someStruct sA
pthread_t rT[10];

int i = 0;
while(i < 10) {
    if(pthread_create(&rT[i], 0, readThread(&sA), &i) != 0) {
        // Error creating child thread
        perror("Cannot create reader thread");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    i++; 
}
```

Is there something blindingly obvious that I am missing here? I can't spot anything that seems to me to e the cause. If i run the pthread_create() whilst attempting to create a single readerThread[0] it executes fine. I can't see the issue.

Comment: Been a while I worked with this, but did you missed an & before "readThread(&sA)" -> "&readThread(&sA)"

Comment: Not the cause, infact adding it causes compilation errors. I have a feeling it's something to do with &rT[i], as when I run the same code outside of a loop with &rT[0] it executes perfectly.

Answer (score 3):

You have to pass the thread entry point.

`readThread(&sA)` is a function call, and will execute the code first... Use `&readThread`.

You have to pass `sA` as the 4th parameter. Either don't pass `i` or put these two together into a struct.

Actually, your code shouldn't compile at all, or I misunderstood something. Please provide *complete*, *minimal* code which reproduces the problem.